# Human readable dynamic segments

Tags: ember.js

I'd my urls to look a little more like /foo/bar/ rather than /foo/23/

Currently I have a route defined as follows

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('category', {path: '/:category_id'}, function() {
     this.route('product', {path: ':product_id'});
  });
});
```

This works as expected. What do I need to change in order to have the url be more human readable? Ideally I'd like both the category and product urls to contain their [unique] names, rather than the unique ids. I've tried changing the path to `/:category_name`, but the url then contains the model object, rather than just the name

Comment: Have a look at http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I thought I read something about serialize but didn't realize it was a hook. Very useful

Comment: I haven't done it before.. but its come up in the IRC channel,, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the serialize function on your Route.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize